# Python library to create forms from JSON schemas

Tags: library, python, json, forms, schema

I know there are several JavaScript libraries to generate forms from a JSON schema (like those mentioned [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20241059/how-to-create-a-form-from-a-json-schema)), but I need to have this work inside a Python project so I would rather not use JavaScript at all. Does such a library exist?